# How to remove order total from cart and checkout page woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I would like to remove order total block on cart and checkout page. 
I am not able to find any action or filter to remove order total. 
I don't want to use css to hide this column.

[image: cart page image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using hooks:

1) Remove cart totals:

```
// On cart page
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_collaterals', 'remove_cart_totals', 9 );
function remove_cart_totals(){
    // Remove cart totals block
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_cart_collaterals', 'woocommerce_cart_totals', 10 );

    // Add back "Proceed to checkout" button (and hooks)
    echo '<div class="cart_totals">';
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_totals' );

    echo '<div class="wc-proceed-to-checkout">';
    do_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout' );
    echo '</div>';

    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_totals' );
    echo '</div><br clear="all">';
}
```

2) Remove checkout totals:

```
// On checkout page
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'remove_checkout_totals', 1 );
function remove_checkout_totals(){
    // Remove cart totals block
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_order_review', 10 );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Answer (score 0):

If its input field you can remove its value like

```
 $('#div_id').val('');
```

If its div or span you can do

```
$("div").empty();
S('#div_id div').html('');
```

Comment: This is better way then css but i was looking for woocommerce hook.
Thanks for your help..