# Hide Order Total from Woocommerce Checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-checkout-fields

I'm trying to hide the "order-total" section from my checkout if the total is 0.00€ (see [Pic here][1] for reference).

I tried to add a condition to the code (as you can see below) I found suggested here:
[How to remove order total from cart and checkout page woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49954483/how-to-remove-order-total-from-cart-and-checkout-page-woocommerce)

However when I try it live, it hides the field even if the cart is not 0.00€.
Here's the code:

```
// On checkout page
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'remove_checkout_totals', 1 );
function remove_checkout_totals(){
    cart_total = WC()->cart->get_cart_total();
    if ( $cart_total == 0 ) {
            // Remove cart totals block
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_order_review', 10 );
    }
}
```

What should I do?
Thanks in advance for you help!

24/09: edit after 7uc1f3r's corrections

Comment: You have a typo: `cart_total` should be `$cart_total` and `if ( $cart_total != 0 )` 
means NOT equal to 0, so change this by `==`

Comment: I corrected it... And we're almost there, so first all of thanks!
However the code deletes the product name, is there a way to cancel only the "order-total" table?

Comment: that is possible, but only if you adjust (overwrite) the template file

Comment: I noticed code deletes order-total field even if cart is not 0.00...I'm bamboozled