# Remove Totals section from WooCommerce Cart while keeping Subtotal line

Tags: php, templates, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, cart

I've found some code from here: [How to remove order total from cart and checkout page woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49954483/how-to-remove-order-total-from-cart-and-checkout-page-woocommerce)

that will  let me remove the entire 'Cart Totals' block from my cart page:

```
//removal of 'Total' block on cart page
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_collaterals', 'remove_cart_totals', 9 );
function remove_cart_totals(){
    // Remove cart totals block
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_cart_collaterals', 'woocommerce_cart_totals', 10 );

    // Add back "Proceed to checkout" button (and hooks)
    echo '<div class="cart_totals">';
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_totals' );

    echo '<div class="wc-proceed-to-checkout">';
    do_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout' );
    echo '</div>';

    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_totals' );
    echo '</div><br clear="all">';
}
```

It works, however, Id like to still keep the subtotal visible. basically, just remove the  'Cart totals' and total section. Is this possible?

[Picture of cart page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAHln.png)

I tried the above code, and it worked to get rid of everything in the totals block, but I want to try and keep the subtotal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep the cart subtotal display while removing all other totals, use the following:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_collaterals', 'keep_only_cart_subtotal', 9 );
function keep_only_cart_subtotal(){
    // Remove cart totals block
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_cart_collaterals', 'woocommerce_cart_totals', 10 );

    // Add back Subtotal, "Proceed to checkout" button (and hooks)
    printf('<div class="cart_totals%s">', ( WC()->customer->has_calculated_shipping() ) ? ' calculated_shipping' : '');

    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_totals' );
    
    ?>
    <table cellspacing="0" class="shop_table shop_table_responsive">
    <tr class="cart-subtotal">
        <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Subtotal', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
        <td data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Subtotal', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php wc_cart_totals_subtotal_html(); ?></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <?php

    echo '<div class="wc-proceed-to-checkout">';

    do_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout' );

    echo '</div>';

    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_totals' );

    echo '</div><br clear="all">';
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and work.